# Understanding conclusion of Proof that a matrix that commutes with all gamma matrices is proportional to the identity matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I am trying to understand why a matrix $M$ that commutes with all gamma matrices $\gamma^\mu $ is proportional to the Identity matrix. I am following example 3.18 in Voja Radovanovic's book on solved QFT problems.
considering the set of 16 linearly independent Gamma matrices:
$$\Gamma^a={\{I,\gamma^\mu,\sigma^{\mu\nu},\gamma_5,\gamma_5\gamma^\mu\}}$$
I understand most of the procedure. I begin with the fact that I can write any Matrix as a sum of the Gamma matrices and separate one of them. (with $\Gamma^b\neq I$):
$$M=\sum_{a}c_a\Gamma^a=c_b\Gamma^b+\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\Gamma^a$$
Now I multiply from the left by $\Gamma_d$ and from the right by $\Gamma^d$, such that $\Gamma^d$ and $\Gamma^b$ anticommute:
$$\Gamma_d M\Gamma^d=c_b\Gamma_d\Gamma^b\Gamma^d+\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\Gamma_d\Gamma^a\Gamma^d$$

Since $M$ by definition commutes with all $\gamma^\mu$, and all $\Gamma^d$ are comprised of said $\gamma^\mu$, $M$ commutes with any $\Gamma^d$. Also, $\Gamma^b$ will anticommute with $\Gamma^d$, and $\Gamma_d\Gamma^d=1$:
$$M=-c_b\Gamma^b+\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\Gamma_d\Gamma^a\Gamma^d$$
But I know that the product of any two $\Gamma$ simply give another $\Gamma$ up to a factor $\eta=+-1 $ or $\eta=+-i$
$$M=-c_b\Gamma^b+\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\eta\Gamma^a$$
Here, I can multiply the first equation as well as the previous one by $\Gamma_b$ and take the trace, giving the following two expressions:
$$Tr(M\Gamma_b)=Tr(c_b\Gamma^b\Gamma_b)+Tr(\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\Gamma^a\Gamma_b)$$
$$Tr(M\Gamma_b)=Tr(-c_b\Gamma^b\Gamma_b)+Tr(\sum_{a\neq b}c_a\eta\Gamma^a\Gamma_b)$$
Clearly, $c_b$ has to be 0 for the first two expressions to be equivalent. But the book now says that it is "obvious" that all $c_a$ terms are $0$ except for the one multiplying the identity matrix, but I do not see how I could draw that conclusion. How can we know that?

Comment: Consider to define what you mean with $\Gamma$.

Comment: By $\Gamma$ I mean one of the 16 dirac gamma matrices. I will edit it in

Comment: Are you familiar with Shur's lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma

Comment: "I begin with the fact that I can write any Matrix as a sum of the Gamma matrices" This is not true. You can write any **4x4 matrix** as a sum of the Gamma matrices. It is a convenient fact that the 16 Gamma matrices turn out to be independent in this sense.

Comment: I am not, but I will read it now. How does it relate to my question?